# Query post with meta value in set of values

Tags: wp-query, get-posts

I am trying to build a query that returns all posts, with a meta value that exists in a set of values.

My posts have a meta key called `Asin_unique` and I want to find all posts, that have the value `B006MWDNVI`,`B00BCMCIS2`, or `B01ARRJFGA` in this field.

This is what I have built so far, but it only returns me the post with `B00BCMCIS2`, not the other ones. What do I have to change to make it work?

```
$args  = array(
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'post_type'   => 'any',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'meta_query'  => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'Asin_unique',
            'value'   => '(B006MWDNVI,B00BCMCIS2,B01ARRJFGA)',
            'compare' => 'IN',
        )
    )
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Answer (score 2):

Check This Will Work for you.

```
$args  = array(
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'post_type'   => 'any',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'meta_query'  => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'Asin_unique',
            'value'   => array('B006MWDNVI','B00BCMCIS2','B01ARRJFGA'),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        )
    )
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Help Link: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/meta_query.html

Comment: Thank you. But this didn't work either. You got me on the right track though, that it has to do something with how the value is formatted. I fooled around with it a bit: If I just leave out the brackets in my example, it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving out the brackets in the value seems to do the trick. I was mislead by how IN is usually formatted in SQL and thought it would be the same with WP queries, but you have to leave them out:

```
$args  = array(
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'post_type'   => 'any',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'meta_query'  => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'Asin_unique',
            'value'   => 'B006MWDNVI,B00BCMCIS2,B01ARRJFGA',
            'compare' => 'IN',
        )
    )
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );
```